# string modification messes formatting in PHP

Tags: php, date, formatting

```
$str = date("d")+1 . date("-m") . date("-y");
$date = new DateTime($str);
echo $date->format('y-m-d ');
```

This works fine, but...

```
$str = date("d")+1 . date("-m") . date("-y");
$date = new DateTime($str);
echo $date->format('d-m-Y ');
```

Strangely, both give different dates

I think it's due to the DateTime constructor, but is there an easy workaround for this?

Comment: What are they outputting?  Is it 13-03-07 and 07-03-2013?

Comment: something like that...

Comment: Improve your code like so: `$date = new DateTime('+1 day')`

Comment: I could not get them to produce output that were different dates. But I did get them to produce different output.

Answer (score 2):

Using an uppercase `Y` in the date format will give you the four digit year. Using a lowercase `y` will give you only two digits.

Comment: I think it works if I use lowercase y, but I want four digits.

Comment: You must use uppercase `Y` in `$date->format` to get four digits. Something like `$date->format('d-m-Y')` or $date->format('Y-m-d')`

Answer (score 2):

`Y` and `y` are different.

But the point is, If you just want to get the date of tomorrow, don't write code like that, just use:

```
$date = new DateTime('+1 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

If you don't care the time, then you could even use:

```
$date = new DateTime('tomorrow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually adding on string `date()` function you can use object `modify`:

```
$str = date("d") . date("m") . date("y");
$time = new DateTime($str);
$time->modify("+1 day");
echo $time->format("d-m-y");
```

Better way:

```
$time = new DateTime("+1 day");
echo $time->format("d-m-y");
```